# How to show only those tickets whose owner are same as login user and there should be no other option to show or open other tickets

Tags: maximo

I have used this condition (owner=:user) in SR where clause and it run correctly.It shows only those SR whose owner is same as login user.But the problem is the other SR will also appear when we go to the All record option.
I want this condition should apply only to the particular group or the selected group.

Answer (score 0):

yes i got answer we can use apply object restriction just put "type=qualified and use this condition expression :owner=:&USERNAME&"

Answer (score 0):

Owner field inherits from personid field so using personid would be safer.
Expression for object restriction would be:

```
OWNER=:&PERSONID&
```